# Activity used as dialog brings up unclosed activities from the stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm using an **Activity-2** with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` as a dialog started from the **Service** with `startIntent()`. When the app is launched, **Activity-1** marked as `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>` is shown and the **Service** is being started.

When the user leaves the app by clicking home button (**Activity-1** is left on the stack) and **Activity-2** is shown by the **Service**, **Activity-1** is visible in the background of the dialog.

Is there a way to launch dialog **Activity** ignoring other activities on the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the `Activity-2` as a new task.

When you start the `Activity-2` from the `service` , do this

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent)
```

Also, make sure the `Activity-1` and `Activity-2` has different `task Affinity` , by default activities in same package will have same 'taskAffinity`as its package name. You can set a differnt 'taskAffinity' for`Actiivty-2` , so that it will be launched in different task.

See here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html
The affinity comes into play in two circumstances:

When the intent that launches an activity contains the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag.
A new activity is, by default, launched into the task of the activity that called startActivity(). It's `pushed onto the same back stack` as the caller. However, if the intent passed to startActivity() contains the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag, the system looks for a different task to house the new activity. Often, it's a new task. However, it doesn't have to be. If there's already an existing task with the same affinity as the new activity, the activity is launched into that task. `If not, it begins a new task`.